# topological $KC$ space

Tags: general-topology

The spaces are called  **$KC$-spaces** in which every compact subset is closed.

> let $(X,\tau_1)$ be a $KC$-topological space, is there a $KC$ topology
>    space $(X, \tau_2)$, so that $ \tau_ 1 \subset \tau_2$?

If there is not this topology, can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you sure that $\tau_1=\tau_2$ is allowed?

Answer (score 1):

The discrete topology on $X$ is a maximal KC-topology.

Comment: Excuse me, I can not  see what you write.can you explain it?

Comment: @adin Discrete topology is Hausdorff, and every compact set is closed in Hausdorff spaces. It is also the finest topology on a space.

Comment: Can I prove that "let a $(X,\tau_1)$ is a $KC$-topological space and $\tau_1 \subset  \tau_2$, is   space $(X, \tau_2)$ a $KC$-topological space  ?

Comment: @adin Yeah, a compact set in $\tau_2$ is still compact in $\tau_1$. Hence it's closed in $\tau_1$, hence closed in $\tau_2$.